# How does valueOf() method works on a date object in JavaScript underneath?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

Given a date :

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(date.valueOf()); // print numeric value : 1587644687189
```

Any documentation mentions that `valueOf()` is an inbuilt function in JavaScript which is used to get the number of milliseconds between ***1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC*** and the given date.

How this function is implemented on a Date object ?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want the native implementation of this method in a given engine? Or what implementation are you asking for?

Comment: "How this function is implemented on a Date object ?" Look at the V8 source code. Or the SpiderMonkey source code. They are free to implement it how they see fit. The ECMAScript standard only says what should be returned from the function.

Comment: What will you do with the information if you get an acceptable answer to this question? How will knowing the answer help you, in other words? (It's OK if you're just curious too, of course.)

Comment: @VLAZ, you got it. I am looking for the native implementation of the method for date objects.

Comment: There is always the [*language specification*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-object.prototype.valueof). `date.valueOf()` simply returns the date's [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range), which is the only [data property](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-properties-of-date-instances) it has.

Answer (score 0):

Date instances are always based on a timestamp value, a number that measures milliseconds from a fixed point in time. The .valueOf() function simply returns that number. The function does not have to *compute* the number of milliseconds; it always has that as effectively a private internal property.

Calling the various mutator functions like `.setMonth()` etc will update that timestamp value. That process is where interesting work is done, such as taking into account daylight savings time and other complexities of calendar math.

Any object can have a `.valueOf()`:

```
console.log(5 + { valueOf: () => 6 }); // 11
```

It can also be placed on the prototype, as is the case with Date objects.